# How can I make this script that reads an excel, then finds and copies files run faster?

Tags: c#, excel, visual-studio, performance

My script reads an excel sheet and gets a range, the range holds the names of different media files, that I add to one big list. I use the names in the list to search a directory, if they exist in the given file directory, then they are added to the "existsAlready" list. If they do not exist in the given file location BUT exist in the copyFiles directory, then they are copied over to the given directory and are added to the "existsAdded" list. If they are not found in either directory, then the files are added to the "existsNegative" list. All 3 lists are printed to separate listboxes.

This all works, however I have found that it runs a little slow:

1) although the excel app is not visible, it still launches for a second and then closes, slowing down the process.

2)the app runs fine/fast if everything exists in the folder or if it has to copy files, however if there are lots of files not found in the directories and can't be copied it runs quite slow, how can I make this faster? I guess it has to do with it having to search the whole directory and not finding anything.

```
            Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application excelApp = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();
            Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Workbook excelWorkbook = excelApp.Workbooks.Open("@Excelfile");
            Excel.Worksheet xlWorkSheet = (Excel.Worksheet)excelWorkbook.Sheets[1];
            excelApp.Visible = false;
            excelApp.ScreenUpdating = false;
            excelApp.DisplayAlerts = false;
            Excel.Range range = xlWorkSheet.get_Range(B1:G1);



 List<string> listFBX = new List<string>();

            foreach (Excel.Range s in range)
            {

                listFiles.Add(s.Text());

            }

        List<string> existsAlready = new List<string>();
        List<string> existsAdded = new List<string>();
        List<string> existsNegative = new List<string>();


foreach (var item in listFiles)
            {




                string curFile = "X:\\Private\\DATA\\PROJECT DATA\\Database\\" + item;
                string copyFrom = "X:\\Private\\DATA\\PROJECT DATA\\FilesToSearch" + item;

            if (File.Exists(curFile))
            {
                existsAlready.Add(item);

            }

            else if (!File.Exists(curFile) && File.Exists(copyFrom))

            {

                File.Copy(copyFrom, curFile, true);
                existsAdded.Add(item);
            }

            else 
            {
                existsNegative.Add(item);
            }



        }


        for (int i = 0; i < existsAlready.Count; i++)
        {

            listBox1.Items.Add(existsAlready.ElementAt(i));
        }



        for (int i = 0; i < existsAdded.Count; i++)
        {
            listBox2.Items.Add(existsAdded.ElementAt(i));
        }



        for (int i = 0; i < existsNegative.Count; i++)
        {
            listBox3.Items.Add(existsNegative.ElementAt(i));
        }
```

Comment: Why do you even need Excel interop in the first place? Why not just use a library capable of natively reading Excel files, such as EPPlus, NPOI. ClosedXML, Office XML SDK, Aspose, etc.

Comment: If Excel Interop is taking a significant proportion of the time and you are reading xlsx files then you would almost certainly be better off using a library such as EPPlus or ClosedXml (https://github.com/ClosedXML/ClosedXML)

Answer (score 1):

Instead of doing a !File.Exists, why not create another list for all fileNames in the Database and for the FilesToSearch directories. Then do a Contains to see if the current file you are iterating through is in that list. Then perform the File.Copy method & adding it to the Exists list.

```
        List<string> databaseFiles = new List<string>(Directory.GetFiles("X:\\Private\\DATA\\PROJECT DATA\\Database"));
        List<string> filesToSearch = new List<string>(Directory.GetFiles("X:\\Private\\DATA\\PROJECT DATA\\FilesToSearch"));

        foreach(var item in listFiles)
        {
            var curFile = Path.Combine("X:\\Private\\DATA\\PROJECT DATA\\Database\\", item);
            var copyFrom = Path.Combine("X:\\Private\\DATA\\PROJECT DATA\\CopyFrom\\", item);
            if (databaseFiles.Contains(curFile))
            {
                existsAlready.Add(item);
            }
            else
            {
                if (filesToSearch.Contains(copyFrom))
                {
                    File.Copy(copyFrom, curFile, true);
                    existsAdded.Add(item);
                }
                else
                {
                    existsNegative.Add(item);
                }
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

With regards to the first point, you can set `excelApp.Visible = false;` as soon as you've declared `excelApp`, i.e. it would be the second line.

With regards to the second point, is it not just that you are having to perform more checks when files aren't there? What kind of time/performance difference is there? You could look at swapping the order of your If statements around if you are expecting many files to not exist.